# Foreign keys, where they belong depending on relationships

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, ddl

I've worked with databases a fair bit (*MySQL, Oracle*) though typically only DML as the systems had been previously engineered.

I'm working on a project as the sole developer, and am responsible for application development, and DBA; the latter of course proving more problematic.

In any case - I need a refresh on foreign key constraints, and their logical placement in a model. Given the following:

```
dbc_user
    .user_id INT, Primary Key, Auto Increment
    // arbitrary columns

dbc_user_profile
    .user_id INT, Primary Key
    // arbitrary columns
```

These tables are a **1-to-1** relationship. I understand that given that relationship, their columns could be consolidated into a single table, but let's just keep them separate. The foreign key belongs then, in the `dbc_user_profile` table?

What about **many-to-many**?

```
dbc_user
    .user_id INT, Primary Key, Auto Increment

dbc_city
    .city_id INT, Primary Key, Auto Increment

dbc_user_city
    .city_id INT, Primary Key
    .user_id INT, Primary Key
```

Which tables are the referencing/referenced tables?

For some reason I can't seem to find a quick and dirty tutorial on this, that explains the relationships.

So two part question;

- Can someone suggest a tutorial for the semi-savvy that hammers out the details of DDL with regard to foreign keys? or;
- Can someone give a quick rundown on **1-to-1**, **1-to-m**, and **m-to-m** relationships and FK references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key is declared on the child table and references the parent table.

In a 1-to-1 relationship, it would appear that `DBC_USER` is the parent and `DBC_USER_PROFILE` is the child.  So you'd declare the foreign key on the `DBC_USER_PROFILE` table and reference the `DBC_USER` table.  Something like (Oracle syntax)

```
CREATE TABLE dbc_user_profile (
  user_id int primary key,
  <<more columns>>
  constraint fk_user_profile_user_id foreign key (user_id)
    references dbc_user( user_id )
)
```

In a 1-to-m relationship, it generally pretty clear which table is the parent and which is the child.  The parent has 1 row for m rows in the child.  So you declare the foreign key on the child table and reference the parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  parent_id int primary key,
  <<additional columns>>
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id int primary key,
  parent_id int references parent( parent_id ),
  <<additional columns>>
);
```

For an m-to-m relationship, the foreign key would be defined on the mapping table and would reference the two parent tables.  So the foreign keys would be declared on the `DBC_USER_CITY` table and would reference both `DBC_USER` and `DBC_CITY`.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbc_user_city (
  city_id int,
  user_id int,
  constraint pk_dbc_user_city primary key( city_id, user_id ),
  constraint fk_dbc_user_city_city_id foreign key( city_id )
    references dbc_city( city_id ),
  constraint fk_dbc_user_city_user_id foreign key( user_id )
    references dbc_user( user_id )
)
```

Obviously, the syntax tends to be relatively database specific.  For Oracle in particular, there is a pretty complete list of the syntax options on the [PSOUG site](http://psoug.org/reference/constraints.html).  For a more general reference that includes syntax for a variety of databases, you could use the [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

Comment: Thank you sir - quick and to the point, though I would strike w3schools; from my understanding, they have led more astray than they have helped.