# Foreign key placement while designing mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

When designing mysql tables are there any rules governing the placement of foreign key?

I.e. Some developers do this.

```
//Place the "address_id" inside the customer table
//Customer Table
Customer_id, Address_id, Customer_Name
    1            1            Jay

//Address Table
Address_id,  City
    1       London
```

And some do this.

```
//Place the "customer_id" inside the address table
//Customer Table
Customer_id, Customer_Name
    1            Jay

//Address Table
Address_id, Customer_id,  City
    1            1       London
```

Which approach is better and why? What these developers consider while making the decisions related to placement of foreign key?

This might be a stupid question and might be obvious for some people. But I am really struggling to clear this confusion and would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you can see the answer here


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576901/foreign-keys-where-they-belong-depending-on-relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st approach allows One Address per Customer and 2nd approach allows multiple addresses per customer. This is totally based on the requirement. for example if you want to record office and home address then 2nd approach is preferred. there are many scenarios to record present and correspondence address, Main Office Address and Branch Address so on.

[Refer Wikipedia on Cardinality (data modelling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29)